# Make <tr> rows clickable and load result in div using jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have two questions:
1. How can I make my table rows clickable and still load ajax content in the div `ajaxContent`? 
2. How can I add a loading-animation in the `<div id='ajaxContent'>`

this is `students.php`

```
<?php

echo "<table id='tblStudents'>\n";

        echo "<thead><tr>\n";
            echo "<td>Namn</td>\n";
            echo "<td>Personnummer</td>\n";
            echo "<td>Startdatum</td>\n";
            echo "<td>Slutdatum</td>\n";
        echo "</tr></thead>\n";

        echo "<tbody>\n";
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($list_students)) {

            $count = ($count + 1) % 2; //will generate 0 or 1 and is used to alternatve the css classes row0 and row1 in the loop result

            echo "<tr class='row$count'>\n";
                echo "<td><a class='ajaxCall' href='#' rel='".$row['student_id']."'>" . $row['student_firstname'] . "</a> " . $row['student_lastname'] . "</td>\n";
                echo "<td>" . $row['student_socialnr'] . "</td>\n";
                echo "<td>" . $row['student_startdate'] . "</td>\n";
                echo "<td>" . $row['student_enddate'] . "</td>\n";


            echo "</tr>\n";
        }
        echo "</table>\n";  
}

?>
<div id='ajaxContent'></div>

<script src="js/jfunc.js"></script>
```

This is `jfunc.js`

```
$('a.ajaxCall').click(function() {
var rowId = $(this).attr('rel');

 $.ajax({
  type: "get",
  url: '/page/editstudent.php',
  data: { student_id: rowId },
  success: function(data) {
  $('#ajaxContent').html(data);
 }
}); 
});
```

Comment: Post your resulting HTML, not your PHP, please. Also, do you want the `<tr>` clickable, or the `<a>` within the first `<td>`?

Comment: I think you need to see the PHP also because of the $count function. I think this will be in the way if I know jQuery right.. Not that I'm good at it but still. I want the complete <tr> clickable.

Comment: The alternating classes will be seen in the resulting HTML. Besides, it's not really relevant to this particular problem.

Comment: While this is off topic for this question, please change `<td>Namn</td>` to `<th scope=\"col\">Namn</th>` and do the same for Personnummer, Startdatum, and Slutdatum.  This will make the table accessible, and more symantec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use event-delegation and listen for all clicks on the table.

```
$("#tblStudents").on("click", "tr", function(e){
    var row_id = $("td:first a.ajaxCall", this).attr("rel");
    $("#ajaxContent").html("Loading...");
    $.ajax({
        url: "/page/editstudent.php",
        data: { 'student_id':row_id },
        success: function(data){
            $("#ajaxContent").html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

#### Side-issues

You don't need to add a classname of `0` or `1` to each table-row. With pure CSS you can target even and odd rows to style them differently:

```
#tblStudents tr:nth-child(even) {
    background: #f1f1f1;
    color: #999;
}
```

Additionally, I would encourage you to store the student id on a data attribute instead of the `rel` attribute. This is what the data attributes exist for. You could even store them on the `<tr>` itself. More about those at http://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I am not able to get this to work though. Nothing happens when I click a row and my firebug says "missing } after property list success: function(data){". Do you mind helping me further?

Comment: @David Sorry, I was missing a comma. Also note that you need to click the `<a>` tag. If  you want to make this work by clicking *anywhere* on the `<tr>` we can make those changes.

Comment: Now it worked better, thank you. Yes I would very much like that function!

Comment: @David I've updated the code to handle clicks on the `<tr>` tag. Please note that this still depends on the `<a>` to get the student id.

Answer (score 0):

1 a add a click event on each tr

```
$('#tblStudents').on('click', 'tr', function(e) {
     // do something
]);
```

1 b prevent the click event bubling on ajaxCall

```
$('a.ajaxCall').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    var rowId = $(this).attr('rel');

    $.ajax({
    type: "get",
    url: '/page/editstudent.php',
    data: { student_id: rowId },
    success: function(data) {
    $('#ajaxContent').html(data);
    }
    });
```

2 before requesting the ajax url, insert an image into ajaxContent. once the request has been completed the image will be overwritten with the new html